# How to toggle numerous text blocks/buttons in different ways, using the same function?

Tags: javascript, button, text, toggle

I have multiple buttons in my HTML-code. I want each button to swap text on click and then swap back again on the next click. It's important that it's only the button you click on that toggle text and also: each button has it's own replacement text.

So far I have managed to make this happen for one text only (id="1"). My biggest problem is not to find examples of how to get elements by multiple IDs even though I would love to get help with this as well. But my biggest problem is to get id="2" to toggle to an individual text on click. I.e. "Hello hello" should change to "Hej hej" on click and "Good bye" should change to "Hejdå" on click.

HTML

```
<button onclick="buttonToggle()" class="link" id="item1"><span id="1">Hello hello</span>/button>

<button onclick="buttonToggle()" class="link" id="item2"><span id="2">Good bye</span></button>
```

Javascript

```
function buttonToggle() {
  var x = document.getElementById("1");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Hello Hello") {
    x.innerHTML = "Hej hej";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Hello Hello";
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. As you have mentioned that you want to access the element with multiple ids, but one element cannot have multiple ids. Also, you can use objects to create an array to handle this for multiple buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that can help to achieve this

```
<button onclick="buttonToggle(event)" class="link" id="item1">Hello hello</button>
<button onclick="buttonToggle(event)" class="link" id="item2">Good bye</button>
```

Script Code : Here I have created array of objects and each object have information about its id, original text and replace text. Which get replaced on button click. You can add multiple buttons in the objects as per your HTML.

```
<script>
        var buttonInformation = [{
            id: 'item1',
            originalText: "Hello Hello",
            replaceText: "Hej hej"
        }, {
            id: 'item2',
            originalText: "Good bye",
            replaceText: "Hejdå"
        }, ]

        function buttonToggle(event) {
            var id = event.currentTarget.id;
            matchingIdObject = buttonInformation.filter(function(e) {
                return e.id === id;
            })
            if (matchingIdObject.length == 1) {
                var x = document.getElementById(id);
                x.innerHTML = matchingIdObject[0].replaceText
                matchingIdObject[0].replaceText = matchingIdObject[0].originalText;
                matchingIdObject[0].originalText = x.innerHTML;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I hope this helps.